# How do I send random embed images with a python bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is what I used:

```
@client.command()
async def testcode(ctx):
  mum = random.choice(test.links)
  
  embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xfff300, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  embed.set_image(url=mum)
  embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by: {ctx.author.name}")
  
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I was using a tutorial on YouTube and copied the code but it still didn't work, I put up a separate file to get the links from but it still doesn't work, I'm trying to embed them too so it's a little more complicated, but I need help nonetheless.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easy way of doing it, it will randomly choose a image link out of the "images" array and display it as an image url in the embed.

```
images = ['https://i.redd.it/123123.jpg', 'etc', 'image link', 'etc', 'image link', 'etc']

@client.command()
async def image(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Random Image",
    colour=discord.Colour(0x7289DA),
    description=f"Random Image",
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1580842764)
    )
    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(images)))


    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Getting more advanced, you can use api's or json file which allow you to take images from other resources online such as:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="r/dankmemes", description="https://www.reddit.com")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
                async with cs.get(
                    'https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
                        res = await r.json()
                        embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'][random.randint(0, 25)]
                                        ['data']['url'])
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But leave that up to you, hope this helps